# Different results in sandbox vs production

Tags: visualforce

I am having an issue with a visualforce page acting differently in the sandbox vs production.  I have a custom field on the contact called First_Language__c, which is a picklist with several values defined (the picklist in the sandbox is identical to the production picklist) that I am using in a visualforce page layout.  This is the definition of the field on the page...

```
<apex:outputPanel id="InternationalOnly">
    <apex:outputText styleclass="tableHeader" value="International Information" rendered="{!admitType=='International'}" />
    <apex:outputText styleclass="tableHeader" value="" rendered="{!admitType=='International'}" />
    <apex:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="Column" rendered="{!admitType=='International'}">
        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Native Language"/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputField value="{!con.First_Language__c}" />
        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Nation of Citizenship"/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputField value="{!con.Citizenship_Country__c}" />
        <apex:panelGroup >
            <apex:outputText styleclass="label" value="Nation of Birth"/>
        </apex:panelGroup>
        <apex:inputField value="{!con.Birth_Country__c}" />
    </apex:panelGrid>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

In the sandbox visualforce page, the text shows Native Language and I get a block that gives me access to the list of values from the picklist.  The other two panelgroups show properly as well.

In production, the text shows Native Language, but I do not get a block that would allow me access to the list of values.  The other two panelgroups show the text values and blocks with access to the list of values - the same as in the sandbox.

I've checked the security access and found no differences as well as no difference in the picklist values and definitions.

What am I missing?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you screenshot the difference, not that the current write is not good but would make it easier to see whats happening

Comment: To clarify, you've checked Field Level Security, Field Dependencies (if applicable), and record types?

Comment: You could try access the Contact via the Standard SF page to make sure that the field is working as expected in both Prod and UAT.

Comment: I tried to add some screen shots, but was unable to.  I checked field level security, field dependencies (none were present), and record types.  I checked in both production and the sandbox to verify that the picklists were identical.  Not sure where else to check.

Comment: silly but due to chrome issues I am asking you this question. Are you trying in the same browser / using chrome for PRD and mozilla for the Sandbox. Try with the same browser.

Comment: I used Mozilla for both production and sandbox.  Just for a test, I tried production and the sandbox VF page in Chrome and had the same results.

Comment: One important thing to add.  In production, it is outside of Salesforce.